# How to instantiate objects of certain type in current AppDomain assemblies with Ninject?

Tags: c#, reflection, ninject, automapper

I'm trying to automate registration of AutoMapper profiles with Ninject. For this I need to instantiate objects of types that inherit from AutoMapper.Profile, for example:

```
public class WordMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Datacontext.Entities.Word, Domain.Entities.Word>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Entities.Word, Datacontext.Entities.Word>();
    }
}
```

First I tried to do this only by means of reflection and it worked like a charm:

```
var profileType = typeof(AutoMapper.Profile);

var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                        .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
                        .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
                        .Cast<Profile>();

foreach (var profile in profiles)
{
    Mapper.AddProfile(profile);
}
```

But when I try to do the same thing with Ninject:

```
public class MappingModules : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom<AutoMapper.Profile>();
        });

        var profiles = Kernel.GetAll<Profile>();
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            Mapper.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> SetUp : Ninject.ActivationException : Error activating Profile using
>   implicit self-binding of Profile No constructor was available to
>   create an instance of the implementation type.
>
> Activation path:   1) Request for Profile
>
> Suggestions:   1) Ensure that the implementation type has a public
>   constructor.   2) If you have implemented the Singleton pattern, use a
>   binding with InSingletonScope() instead.

I suspect that this happens because of Ninject trying to instantiate Mapper.Profile itself but it doesn't have a public constructor. But when I change `.InheritedFrom<AutoMapper.Profile>()` to `.Where(p => p.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(AutoMapper.Profile)) && p != typeof(AutoMapper.Profile))` it doesn't help either.

It's worth to mention that Ninject's composition root, Ninject' modules and classes inherited from `AutoMapper.Profile` are located in 3 different assemblies.

Help me please to figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your convention based binding is missing.... the binding!
Add a `.BindBase()` to the end of the conditional binding.

```
    Kernel.Bind(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom<AutoMapper.Profile>()
            .BindBase();
    });
```

`BindBase()` will bind the class to it's immediate base class, which in your example (`WordMapping : Profile`) is `Profile`. If your inheritance hierarchy would be `WordMapping : MyMapping : Profile` it would bind to `MyMapping` (which would not be okay for you).
So if you need it to be bound to a different type, have a look at https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Projecting-Services-to-Bind

Comment: This appears to work but I don't understand how... Profile has a protected constructor.  There is a public Initialize() but I don't see how ninject would know to call this method.  Now I'm worried my profiles are not loading correctly.

Comment: Ok I checked the source and Profile.Initialize is called from within Mapper.Initialize.  But it still expects a new'd up Profile instance.  How is it doing that with a protected ctor?  I also see an internal ctor but it expects a string.  Too much magic here ;o)

Comment: You're right, ninject can't call `new Profile()` - and it doesn't have to. It's actually calling `new WordMapping()`. And since `WordMapping : Profile`, it can be safely "casted" to `Profile` _after_ instantiation.